# Javascript - forEach is not a function API

Tags: javascript, html, api, foreach, html-table

I am using an API within javascript using fetch to get data and place it into a table, but I keep on getting a type error saying that the .forEach is not a function.

Below I am pasting my HTML and JavaScript.

HTML:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Player Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Nationality</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Personal API Key
var apiKey = '⟨the key⟩';

function requestLeagueTable() {
  fetch('https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/scorers', {
      headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': apiKey,
      }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Data :', data);
      createTable(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

// create the table
function createTable(data) {
  var players = data.scorers[0].player;
  var teams = data.scorers[0].team;
  var goals = data.scorers[0].numberOfGoals;

  players.forEach(createTeam);
  teams.forEach(createTeam);
  goals.forEach(createTeam);
}

function createTeam(player, team, goal) {
  // create an element for each element
  var teamElement = document.createElement("tr");

  // add each individual piece of data
  addTeamData(player.name, teamElement);
  addTeamData(team.name, teamElement);
  addTeamData(player.position, teamElement);
  addTeamData(player.nationality, teamElement);
  addTeamData(goal, teamElement);

  // add the team to the page
  var tableElement = document.querySelector("tbody");
  tableElement.appendChild(teamElement);
}

// add each individual piece of team data
function addTeamData(data, element) {
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.textContent = data;
  element.appendChild(td);
}

// update on page load
requestLeagueTable();
```

[image: Console of Data]

If you could help me out, would be very beneficial.

Many thanks

Comment: `players`, `teams` or `goals` might be `undefined`?

Comment: ^... or they're not arrays.

Comment: @Teemu I have added an image of the console data

Comment: The images tells `players` and `teams` being an object, and `goals` being a number. Also, the callback function of `forEach` gets value, index and array of the current value of the iteration passed, it won't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @Teemu So how can I make this work?

Comment: I've no clue what you actually have. Please add an example of the data as an array (real code), then we might know what is needed.

Comment: `data.scorers.forEach(({player, team, numberOfGoals}) => createTeam(player, team, numberOfGoals));`. Alternatively, `.forEach(createTeam)`, change function header to `function createTeam({player, team, numberOfGoals})`, and adjust variables accordingly. `data.scorers` is the array you want to iterate over. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you so much that really helped

Comment: Use `let players = data.scorers[0].player || [];`, so undefined will be an empty array and forEach won't break.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I did it was like this:

```
function createTable(data) {
data.scorers.forEach(({player, team, numberOfGoals}) => createTeam(player, team, numberOfGoals));
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: Yes it is an answer

Answer (score 1):

your trying to do a forEach on:

```
 var goals = data.scorers[0].numberOfGoals;
```

so `goals` is not an array, so you can't do forEach on it.

Comment: How can I make it work and show the data in a table?

Comment: wich value do you want to show. and please validate the answer.

Comment: I want to show the players, teams and goals within the table

Comment: do a loop on all the soccers and then inside of it get their data.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: ``` var players = data.scorers.player;
  for (var i = 0; i < players; i++) {
   var obj = data.scorers.player[i];
  }```